# How can I make page slide onto the screen when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I basically have a menu that slides onto the screen when you press a button. And on the menu I have a few buttons that currently don't do anything. What I want them to do is whenever a user clicks on a button I want the page to slide in from the bottom of the screen. I have tried to do this myself but for some reason it just closes the menu whenever I press one of the buttons.

Here is what I have so far.

```js
//About Page Transition
function expand(){
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $(".aboutContent").toggleClass("active");
};
$("#about").on('click', expand);

//Projects Page Transition
function expand(){
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $(".aboutContent").toggleClass("active");
};
$("#projects").on('click', expand);

//Contact Page Transition
function expand(){
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $(".aboutContent").toggleClass("active");
};
$("#contact").on('click', expand);

//Menu Transition
function expand(){
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
};
$(".button").on('click', expand);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#aboutContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#projectsContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#contactContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(60, 106, 152, 0.8);
  width: 18%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
}

.active {
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:60%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  cursor: default;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  font-size:14px;
}

li {
  padding:10px 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px 15px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:"Roboto";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #d66863;
}

.content {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
}

.button {
  width:20px;
  height:40px;
  margin:24% 36%;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.line {
 width: 40px;
 height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

.line.first {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.line.second {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}

.button.on .line.top {
 transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}

.button.on .line.bottom {
 transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head> 
<body>
    
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
      
    <h1>Title</h1>
      
    <ul>
       <div id="home"><li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> home</a></li></div>
       <div id="about"><li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> about</a></li></div>
       <div id="projects"><li><a href="#projects"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects</a></li></div>
       <div id="contact"><li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact</a></li></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
    
  <div class="content">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="line first top"></div>
      <div class="line second bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    <div id="aboutContent">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="projectsContent">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="contactContent">
    
    </div>
    
</div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy way to do this is with "animate.css".

All you do is dynamically apply the classes "animate slideInUp" (I think that's it anyway) to whatever element you want to slide in, and it just does.

You can do it with plain ol' JS, JQuery makes it braindead easy, bind it as a property in Angular/React (e.g. [ngClass]="theClasses"), however you want.

In your case in fact, you wouldn't even have to dynamically do anything. Just hardcode the classes to the topmost div (or whatever) of the HTML page that loads in. Every time that page loads in, it'll slide up.

Check out animate.css, it's a great and powerful tool and delivers exactly what it says it does, "just add water animations". For basic DOM element animation I've never had to look anywhere else.

You can see it at work on my little personal website:

http://www.tcoz.com

Every time you click a menu button, the page slides in.

Comment: Ok, so I just downloaded it but how would I make it work with my menu buttons? Could you give me an example?

Comment: I assume your buttons already load the pages you want loaded. Each of those pages probably has a top level container of some kind, a div or some such. If they don't, just wrap everything on the page in a div. To that top level container, apply class="animated whateverAnimILike". Now, every time that page loads, that animation style will apply. It's actually that easy.

Comment: Well the problem is I don't want my pages to load. So I need the page to slide out when the button is clicked.

Comment: Hmm, you said you wanted: "What I want them to do is whenever a user clicks on a button I want the page to slide in from the bottom of the screen." And this will definitely do that. You can still do what you want, but now you have to dynamically apply styles and use the "animation finish" capability. It's a more involved answer, unfortunately I don't have time to code up a sample, but the examples on the animate.css site should help.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this: $("#about").addEventListener("click", $(".aboutContent").toggleClass("animated slideInUp"));

Comment: nvm I figured it out! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

make the width in .menu css 100%

Comment: I don't want the menu to take up the entire screen tho. I want it to take a portion of the left side which it already does. I am talking about the buttons on the menu.